# ¿Cómo puedo insertar datos en una tabla automáticamente en función de la opción marcada en un radioGroup? - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, sqlite

estoy realizando un proyecto en Android Studio y tengo problemas para insertar registros en dos de las tablas. La idea es primero insertar datos en una de las tablas (LibrosTotales) y según la opción elegida en un RadioGroup, se inserte en una tabla u otra (LibrosLeídos y LibrosPendientes). Si bien el registro en la tabla principal se realiza correctamente pero en las otras dos no se produce. Lo he comprobado a través de unos rawQuery para ver si hay registros. En el de LibrosTotales sí se produce el registro, pero en LibrosLeídos no. No sñe  si el problema está en la base de datos en sí o hay algo que falla en la lógica de mi programa.

Aquí dejo el código de la base de datos:

````
   
   package Programa
   
   import android.content.Context
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
   
   class DBSQLiteHelper (context: Context?, name: String?, factory: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory?, version: Int) :
           SQLiteOpenHelper(context, name, factory, version) {
   
           override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
               db.execSQL(
                   "CREATE TABLE '$librosTotales' ( " +
                           "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                           "titulo TEXT NOT NULL," +
                           "autor TEXT NOT NULL," +
                           "comentario TEXT," +
                           "leidoono BOOLEAN)"
               )
                   db.execSQL(
                   "CREATE TABLE '$librosLeidos' ( " +
                           "id_leidos INTEGER PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES librosTotales(id)," +
                           "titulo TEXT NOT NULL," +
                           "autor TEXT NOT NULL," +
                           "comentario TEXT)"
               )
                   db.execSQL(
                   "CREATE TABLE '$librosPendientes' ( " +
                           "id_pendientes INTEGER PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES librosTotales(id)," +
                           "titulo TEXT NOT NULL," +
                           "autor TEXT NOT NULL," +
                           "comentario TEXT)"
               )
   
   
           }
   
           override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
               db.execSQL("DROP TABLE $librosTotales")
               db.execSQL("DROP TABLE $librosLeidos")
               db.execSQL("DROP TABLE $librosPendientes")
               onCreate(db)
           } 
   
           companion object {
               private const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
               private const val NAME_DATABASE = "LIBROS"
               private const val librosTotales = "librosTotales"
               private const val librosLeidos = "librosLeidos"
               private const val librosPendientes = "librosPendientes"
           }
   
       } ```

Esta es la clase en la que pretendo realizar la inserción (parte del código lo comenté para comprobar si hay registros mediante mensajes de consola:

   ```
   package Programa
   
   import android.content.ContentValues
   import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
   import android.content.Context
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
   import android.os.Bundle
   import android.util.Log
   import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
   import android.widget.Button
   import android.widget.EditText
   import android.widget.RadioGroup
   import android.widget.Toast
   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
   import com.example.organizarlibros.R
   
   
   
   class annadirLibro : AppCompatActivity() {
   
       var autor:EditText?=null;
       var titulo: EditText?=null;
       var comentario:EditText?=null;
       var leidoono:RadioGroup?=null;
       lateinit var con:DBSQLiteHelper;
   
   
   
       override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_annadir_libro);
   
           val buttonAnnadir = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonAnnadir)
           val introduct = ContentValues()
           val con = DBSQLiteHelper(this, "librosTotales", null, 2)
           var baseDatos = con.writableDatabase;
           var leerono = false;
   
       
               fun enviarDatos(){
                   introduct.put("autor", autor?.getText().toString())
                   introduct.put("titulo", titulo?.getText().toString())
                   introduct.put("comentario", comentario?.getText().toString())
                   if (leidoono?.checkedRadioButtonId ==R.id.leido) {
                       introduct.put("leidoono", "Leído")
                       leerono=true
                      // baseDatos.insert("librosTotales", null, introduct)
                      // introduct.put("autor", autor?.getText().toString())
                      // introduct.put("titulo", titulo?.getText().toString())
                     //  introduct.put("comentario", comentario?.getText().toString())
                     //  baseDatos.insert("librosLeidos", null, introduct)
                   }
                   else if(leidoono?.checkedRadioButtonId ==R.id.noleido){
                       introduct.put("leidoono", "No Leído")
                       leerono=false
                       //baseDatos.insert("librosTotales", null, introduct)
                       //introduct.put("autor", autor?.getText().toString())
                       //introduct.put("titulo", titulo?.getText().toString())
                       //introduct.put("comentario", comentario?.getText().toString())
                       //baseDatos.insert("LibrosPendientes", null, introduct)
                   };
                   baseDatos.insert("librosTotales", null, introduct)
                 //  val comprobar = baseDatos.rawQuery("SELECT leidoono from librosLeidos", null)
   
                   if(leerono){
                       introduct.put("autor", autor?.getText().toString())
                       introduct.put("titulo", titulo?.getText().toString())
                       introduct.put("comentario", comentario?.getText().toString())
                       baseDatos.insert("librosLeidos", null, introduct)
                   }else{
                       introduct.put("autor", autor?.getText().toString())
                       introduct.put("titulo", titulo?.getText().toString())
                       introduct.put("comentario", comentario?.getText().toString())
                       baseDatos.insert("librosPendientes", null, introduct)
                   }
   
                   var contar = baseDatos.rawQuery("SELECT * from librosLeidos", null)
                   if (contar.moveToFirst()){
                       Log.i(TAG, "sí hay tabla")
                   }else{
                       Log.i(TAG, "no hay tabla")
                   }
   
                   // baseDatos.close()
               }
   
               buttonAnnadir.setOnClickListener(){
                   enviarDatos();
                   //onRadioButtonClicked();
                 //  elegirTabla();
                   val cerrarTablero: InputMethodManager =
                       getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                   cerrarTablero.hideSoftInputFromWindow(buttonAnnadir.windowToken, 0)
                  // if( baseDatos != null){
                       Toast.makeText(this, "Enviando datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                   }
                  // else{
                     //  Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudo enviar datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                   }
   
   } ```

Este es el layout correspondiente:

   ``` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="#A59C9C"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
   
       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical">
   
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/textView1"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="58dp"
               android:layout_weight="150 "
               android:text="POR FAVOR, INTRODUZCA LOS DATOS"
               android:textSize="20sp" />
   
           <EditText
               android:id="@+id/Autor"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="50dp"
               android:layout_weight="150 "
               android:ems="10"
               android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
               android:hint="Autor" />
   
           <EditText
               android:id="@+id/Titulo"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:width="1000dp"
               android:height="50dp"
               android:hint="Título"
               android:textSize="20dp" />
       </LinearLayout>
   
       <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical">
           <RadioButton android:id="@+id/leido"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="LEÍDO" />
           <RadioButton android:id="@+id/noleido"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="PENDIENTE" />
       </RadioGroup>
   
       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/edicion_text"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="150dp"
           android:hint="Introduzca aquí las notas"
           android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
           android:gravity="top"/>
   
   
       <Button
           android:id="@+id/buttonAnnadir"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="ACEPTAR"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
   
       <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="#A59C9C"
           android:visibility="visible"
           tools:context=".librosLeidos"
           tools:visibility="visible">
   
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
   
   
    ```
````

Comment: Cual es el error desplegado en el LogCat?, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Gracias, he reformulado la pregunta, espero que quede más claro